# SwiftUI state variable asymmetric transition

Tags: swiftui

Is it possible to change an asymmetric transition while on screen. For example, the text has a asymmetric transition of

`.transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing) removal: .move(edge: .leading)))`

While the text is on the screen the transition needs to be changed to this

`.transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing) removal: .opacity))`

I have created a test program which uses a `@State` variable that changes the transitions. The issue is when trying to change the `removal` transition after the view has been `insertion`

To simulate the problem with the code below simply press "animate text" then  "change animation" then "animate text". You will see the change animation has no effect until you press "animate text" a third time (when the text is off the screen).

```
import SwiftUI
// Xcode 11.3
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var buttonClick: Bool = false

    @State var showText: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10){
            if showText == true{
                Text("hello")
                    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: buttonClick ? .move(edge: .trailing) : .opacity, removal: buttonClick ? .move(edge: .leading) : .opacity))
            }

            Button (action: { withAnimation { self.buttonClick.toggle() } }) {
                Text("change transition")
            }
            Button (action: { withAnimation { self.showText.toggle() }}) {
                Text("Animate text")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Works as expected. Transition have effect on view "inserting" and "removing", so once inserted the transitioning view constructed with specified parameters and in a stack. Your "change transition" action neither insert nor remove the view, so no changes - you changed only state, which will have effect with the next view reconstruction.

Comment: @Asperi From my little experience with swiftUI. I assumed the asymmetric modifier parameters are State changeable; like almost all default modifiers. Thanks for your comment. Maybe the answer is a custom modifier.

Comment: I'm curious to know if you found a way to change removal transition @snoopDogg ?

Comment: @Asperi if the button was toggling showText it would remove the view, yet the removal transition wouldn’t change because it’s set at view creation. (I believe) and I don’t know how to change that. No Idea.